# Resolving merge conflicts in the TFS API

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I am trying to resolve merge conflicts with the `TFS API` and am struggling.  My issue is as follows:

1. Merge from trunk -> branch
2. Conflict occurs during merge (same line of a file edited in both)
3. At this point I simply want to supply my own text for what the merged file should look like and then mark it as resolved.

I can't work out how to do this.  See code below:

```
// merge was performed and there are conflicts to resolve
Conflict[] conflicts = ws.QueryConflicts(new string[] {"$/ProjectName/solution/"}, true);
Console.WriteLine(" - Conflicts: {0}", conflicts.Count());

if (conflicts.Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine(" - Resolving conflicts");

    // There are conflicts to deal with
    foreach (Conflict conflict in conflicts)
    {
        // Attempt to perform merge internally
        ws.MergeContent(conflict, false);

        if (conflict.ContentMergeSummary.TotalConflicting > 0)
        {
            // Conflict was not resolved
            // Manually resolve  
            // PROBLEM IS HERE <--------------
            var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(conflict.TargetLocalItem).ToList();
            allLines.Add("This is the MANUAL merge result");
            File.WriteAllLines(conflict.TargetLocalItem, allLines.ToArray());
        }

        //conflict was resolved
        conflict.Resolution = Resolution.AcceptMerge;
        ws.ResolveConflict(conflict);
    }
}

Checkin(ws, "Merge comment");
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

As you can see I am trying to manually edit the target file, but this does not work.  I can't seem to work out what file I should be editing on the `conflict` object to manually perform the merge.

One commenter has asked me to elaborate on the issues with the code above:

1. At the point of the comment "PROBLEM IS HERE", the target file still has a read only flag on it, so I cannot edit the file.
2. if I remove the readonly flag with some code and continue with the code, the resulting file does not contain my new line, but contains a diff style text with all the comments in.  I can elaborate on this if it doesn't make sense.
3. If I pend an edit on the `TargetLocalItem`, this does nothing.  No edit is pended.
4. This tells me that editing the target file in the local workspace is not the correct action.

Essentially I am trying to mimic what an external tool does, but my program will be the external tool and provide the merged text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string tmpOutFile = Path.GetTempFileName();    
conflict.MergedFileName = tmpOutFile;                                   
// do stuff with tmpOutFile
conflict.Resolution = Resolution.AcceptMerge;
ws.ResolveConflict(conflict);
```